# Typescript react class: add State type as interface or null

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In react, when we use typescript a typical state type is declared as follows

```
import * as React from "react"

interface IState {
  someState: string
}

class MyClass extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
  state = {
    someState: "test"
  }

  // etc...
}
```

My issue now is that I also want `state = null` to be valid i.e. I know that I can make `someState` optional via `someState?`, but how can I still use `IState` interface on my class while making state nullable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very reacty to have the *entire* state be `null`, but I don't see why this wouldn't work:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface IState {
  someState: string;
}

type INullableState = IState | null;

class MyClass extends React.Component<{}, INullableState> {
  state = {
    someState: "test",
  };

  // etc...
}
```